# Проблемы с пакетом ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Проблема с пакетом linux-headers-4.10.0-21 (4.10.0-21.23)
`sudo apt-get install -f` выдает в конце

```
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 265900 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/linux-headers-4.10.0-21_4.10.0-21.23_all.deb …
Распаковывается linux-headers-4.10.0-21 (4.10.0-21.23) …
dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.10.0-21_4.10.0-21.23_all.deb (--unpack):
не удалось открыть «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-21/arch/mips/include/asm/sibyte/sb1250_regs.h.dpkg-new»: Операция не позволена
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.10.0-21_4.10.0-21.23_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`sudo apt-get dist-update` пишет что

```
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
linux-headers-4.10.0-21-generic : Зависит: linux-headers-4.10.0-21 но он не установлен
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt --fix-broken install», не указывая имени пакета, (или найдите другое решение).
```

`ls -al /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-21/arch/mips/include/asm/sibyt‌​e/; ls -ld /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-21/arch/mips/include/asm/sibyt‌​e/` вывел

```
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-
21/arch/mips/include/asm/sibyt‌​e/': Нет такого файла или каталога
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-
21/arch/mips/include/asm/sibyt‌​e/': Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Comment: предложенную команду выполнили? с каким результатом? дополните выводом этой команды ваш вопрос, нажав [edit]

Comment: приложите (к тексту вопроса) заодно и вывод команды `$ ls -al /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-21/arch/mips/include/asm/sibyte/; ls -ld /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-21/arch/mips/include/asm/sibyte/`